How widespread is ithread support in system perls?
I am contemplating using threads (ithreads) in a module eventually destined for CPAN. Are there any resources I could look at to see which system perls currently compile with useithreads=define by default?
Asyncronicity is central to my module's purpose. I'll be able to implement a non-threaded fallback, but thanks to a lot of blocking IO and other long running functions, the user experience will be worse without threads. I can iron out most of that, at the cost of significantly complicated code. Threads are a natural fit.
Therefore the reason I ask, is simply to help me move the needle between "worse user experience" and "more complicated code", or just "sorry, this requires threading support".

If the user needs your module, they can easily install a threaded perl using perlbrew (or build from source) on any system. So I would not be to worried about the system perl. Also, on macOS the user is generally discouraged from using the system perl to install modules since apple has done certain changes to it that makes it more painful to install extra modules.

Also on Windows, there is no system perl. The user usually installs Strawberry perl there and it comes with thread support by default.

Those points would be great as part of a larger answer that includes distributions that do/don't include a system perl. Re: perlbrew: I use it all the time, but it's beyond the scope, as I'm specifically asking about system perls (which pre-supposes that there IS a system perl). Basically, perl -V from as many freshly installed systems as one could get their hands on. If it returns "perl: command not found" or somesuch, that's a result, too. :-)

I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and it's system perl is compiled with thread support: /usr/bin/perl -V | grep useithreads gives output: useithreads=define. Also perl is installed by default on Ubuntu (confirmed by running docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash and then perl -V). So one way to determine whether the system perl is compiled with thread support would be to manually run docker containers for all systems you are interested in and then execute perl -V | grep useithreads

Simpler: perl -V:useithreads

@HåkonHægland Yes, that's basically what I was referring to with my perl -V comment. Spinning up a dozen or more of the most common distros is the very thing I hoped to avoid (at least in part), by asking this question, but if I don't get any answers, I have other methods... :-) You've given me info for Win/Mac and Ubuntu 24.04 already, so you might consider putting those in an answer, at least. Partial results count.

I'm not going to post this as an answer, but I found a guy named Claude hanging out in front of a closed Fry's Electronics with a sign "Will prompt for shrooms". I asked: "Please list the current versions of actively-maintained Linux distributions with their release dates and the URL for obtaining their latest release, showing whether they come with Perl installed, and if so, which version of Perl and whether that installation of Perl has threads enabled (useithreads='define')." They listed seven Linux releases as recent as 2022, gave the same answer each time - and all had threaded Perl!

By a "system" perl we mean a perl that comes preinstalled with the operating system, or can be installed with the operating system's package manager. The concept of system perl is most relevant on Linux. On macOS, Apple has deprecated the system perl since 2019, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes#3318257 and it is generally not recommended to use it for installing extra perl modules. On Windows, there is no system perl but one usually installs Strawberry Perl.
To check if perl support threads, we can run
$ perl -V:useithreads

If the output is useithreads='define'; the perl was compiled with thread support. If the output is useithreads='undef'; it was not compiled with thread support.
Since the user on macOS and Windows do not use a system perl, we could check if the most commonly installed perl supports threads there instead. And it does: both homebrew perl on macOS and Strawberry perl on Windows support threads.
Now returning to Linux, one way to check if a Linux distro's system perl supports threads is to use docker. For example, to check if the system perl in Ubuntu 24.04 supports threads, we can run:
$ docker run --rm ubuntu:latest perl -V:useithreads
useithreads='define';

I also tested on debian (running docker from Ubuntu 24.04):
$ docker run --rm debian:latest perl -V:useithreads
useithreads='define';

and on centOS:
$ docker run --rm centos:latest perl -V:useithreads
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "perl": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

which means that centos does not come with perl preinstalled. But if we install it with the package manager:
$ docker run --rm -it centos:latest /bin/bash
# yum install -y perl
# perl -V:useithreads
useithreads='define';

So from these three tests it seems like the system perl on Linux might in general support threads, but we need to check more systems to be sure. Let me know if I should test other Linux distros for this.
